# Converting FF Checkbox Group to native or P&T checkboxes

Tags: ee2-upgrades, pt-checkboxes, checkbox

I'm converting an EE 1.x site to the latest 2.x version and have run into a problem where FF Checkbox Groups were used which stored their data as a serialized array whereas both the native and P&T checkbox fieldtypes aren't.

What are my options for upgrading/changing the data?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried (after making a backup) changing your FF Checkbox fieldtype to the P&T one?  It's been awhile since then so I did double check, and found this [post](https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/fieldtypes_causing_problems_in_upgrade_to_ee2#reply_4283900) confirming that is all that should be needed.

If that isn't working, can you confirm what versions you're going to and from?

Thank you!

-Lisa, P&T

Comment: It's a while since this upgrade first began but I think I might've manually edited the exp_channel_fields table because I was getting errors from those fieldtypes that didn't exist anymore. Upgrade went from 1.6.9 up to 2.5.5 with Matrix 2.5.3.

Comment: Ok, so at this point, you have an FF Checkbox Groups with data, that is set to... what type of field?

Comment: Well they're no longer FF groups because I manually changed them to first P&T checkbox group and then native checkboxes (when I realised the problem to see if it made any difference).

Comment: Tyssen, what was the exact output/problem after converting them to P&T checkboxes?

Comment: Nothing gets output in the template because nothing's actually selected, i.e. if you view an entry in the CP, none of the boxes are checked.

Comment: Tyssen, I've sent an email to some of my devs asking for them to look here.  I'll follow up when I hear back.  :)

Comment: Tyssen, is it possible to get a look at this database? If it's not huge, can you email it via support@pixelandtonic.com? Thank you!